# There exist such f, f'

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

My question is:

There exist a function $f = f(x)$ that satisfy

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$$
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = +\infty$$
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x) = +\infty$$
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f'(x) = +\infty$$

Another (related) question:

There exist $g = g(x)$ that satisfy

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} g(x) = +\infty$$
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} g(x) = +\infty$$

And $g'(x) \ge 0 \ \forall x$?

Comment: If $f,g$ are polynomials, then they must have some even degree.

Comment: Note for the second question that $g$ is increasing.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar but polynomials are not going to work.. for example $f = x^{2n}$ does not satisfy the request, plus every polynomial is $\sim$ to it's highest power.. so I think that rules out polynomials

Comment: @Ant: Yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about real valued everywhere differentiable functions.

The second part is quick: No, no such $g$ can exist. $g^\prime \geq 0$ says that $g$ is non-decreasing. However, since $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} g(x) = \infty$, it is the case that there is some $x <0$ such that $g(x) >g(0)$ (can you prove this?). So at some point $g$ is decreasing on the interval $(x,0)$.

The exact same trick works on the first part- try and write down a proof.